# MacOS: How do I remove an unwanted icon association for files with no extension

Tags: macos, icons, finder

My mac is showing an incorrect icon for files with no extension.  This icon is associated with an app I installed, Epson Print CD, and still shows even though I have uninstalled this app.

This is on macOS Ventura (13.13).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it fixed.  Here is what I did:

I used the following command to open all .icns files so that I could find the culprit:

`find /Applications -name '*.icns' -execdir open {} ";"`

And this is how I figured out that the bad icon belonged to Epson Print CD.  I uninstalled the application and then ran the following command to try and clear my icon cache:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

And then I rebooted, and yet that icon still remained for files of no type.  As in, a file named `myfile`, not `myfile.txt` for example.

I deleted the .DS_Store file in a directory containing one these extensionless files.

I reset my Finder preferences with the following command:
`rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist;killall Finder`

I used File > Get Info on one of the files and low and behold it showed the correct, generic icon in the Get Info Preview panel.  When I closed the get info panel, the icon updated in Finder.  New files created with no extension used the correct generic icon, and existing files in other folders are now showing correctly as well.